# App local database

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Not sure, if this is important: app is written with react-native.
Question is about both iOS and android apps.

I have a static database, which contains currently ~9000 rows, each row contains 45 columns and about 280 letters total in it. So, basically, database is relatively small. I'll need to perform pattern search (equivalent of `ILIKE` in Postgres) and sorting based on misc columns with numeric values. No insertions, no modifications, no relations with other "Tables" required.

Should i write nodejs server, instantiate PG database, connect app through web-socket and start querying data from pg, or should i just somehow create local database in app and search through it right in app? The local db is way simpler but I'm worry about performance. If nothing wrong with performance, then what if the database will grow to 15000? 50000?

Answer (score 0):

If the database can be local and there's no need for it to ever be persisted on servers, then you should probably explore [Realm](https://realm.io/). I have not heard of how it great it performs with a lot of data but it acts as a database engine in your phone and has indexing as well.